# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method,

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am trying to implement a method where the keywords stored in the database for an activity (split by a comma) match the giving string split by a comma.

```
public List<TblActivities> SearchByMultipleKeyword(string keywords)
{
    string[] keyword = keywords.Split(',');
    var results  = (from a in Entities.TblActivities
                    where a.Keywords.Split(',').Any(p => keyword.Contains(p))
                    select a).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: The error states that you can't use the functions, as they aren't available (There is no mapping done between those functions and TSQL) A better option may be to use context.ExecuteStoreQuery where you can write the SQL yourself

Comment: Did you look at the related questions over on the right hand side? A cursory glance suggests you'll find your answer reasonably quickly...

Comment: @3dd Can't disagree with you more. The correct option is to actually normalize the database so you can actually use SQL, and indices and table statistics. Otherwise, what is the point of using an RDBMS. If you really want to do this CSV gubbins, use a schemaless database instead!

Comment: @Aron not necessarily true, we don't know the context of the keywords column, it might not be normalizable, but I do agree, if it was normalized it would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queries that do not involve too many keywords and too many rows you could implement this simple and quick solution. You can easily get around the Split function by repeatedly refining your results as follows:

```
 public List<TblActivities> SearchByMultipleKeyword(string keywords)
 {
     string[] keywords = pKeywords.Split(',');

     var results = Entities.TblActivities.AsQueryable();    

     foreach(string k in keywords){

         results  = from a in results
                    where a.Keywords.Contains(k)
                    select a;
     }
     return results.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code sample.  It should say SearchByMultipleKeyword(string pKeywords) - note the "pKeywords" instead of simply keywords"

Comment: This is not a good solution - it would produce a lot of sql queries/requests to the database.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot do this using the Entity Framework, as the error message says.

However, there are options.

One option is to realize that, if keywords are stored as `A,B,C,D`, then `x` is in there if

```
a.Keywords.StartsWith(x + ",") || 
a.Keywords.Contains("," + x + ",") || 
a.Keywords.EndsWith("," + x)
```

That works if `x` does not contain `,` itself. The downside is that this will do a full scan of the table, or of an index containing the `Keywords` column.

The other option is to normalize your database. After all, you have a one to many relationship between activity and keyword. Then model it as such: in addition to an `Activities` table (without the Keywords column), have a `KeyWords` table with two columns, a foreign key to your activities table, and a `keyword` column. This will allow you add an index on the `keyword` column, which can make the query super-fast.

**UPDATE**

I reread your question, and noticed that you are not testing for keyword equality, but just `Contains`. If so, why don't you just do the following?

```
a.Keywords.Contains(x)
```

Comment: would have been nice for EF / Linq-to-Entities to support String.Split().I agree with the first option selected.

Comment: You forgot the case where you have only A stored. Add this : 
a.Keywords.StartsWith(x) ||

Comment: @user_s I would suggest `a.Keywords == x ||` instead. This deals with the problem where the A keyword could be the start of a longer keyword.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can do it like that:

```
public List<TblActivities> SearchByMultipleKeyword(string keywords)
{
    string[] keywordsSeparated = keywords.Split(',');
    var results  = (from a in Entities.TblActivities
                    where keywordsSeparated.Any(keyword => a.Keywords.Contains(keyword))
                    select a).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this hasn't been upvoted - it's the only correct and credible answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohnOhara.  This worked PERFECTLY for me.  I used this and compared the result to the the SQL script I was trying to achieve in SSMS.

Comment: @JohnOhara the crucial question is: what is the content of `a.Keywords`. The code provided in this answer will just do a flat string-contains on `a.Keywords` without splitting it in its components. So if one of the keywords is `A` and `a.Keywords` is `FOO,BAR`, that entity will be selected just because the letter `A` is contained in `FOO,BAR`. But depending on your keywords and what your looking for this method might be acceptable. E.g. if the keywords are a list of GUIDs and your looking for entire GUIDs.

Answer (score 5):

`String.Split` isn't supported by Entity Framework. This is simply because there is no equivalent in SQL.

A solution is:

1. to define a custom function in the database
   This article proposes several solutions: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
2. to declare this function usable by LINQ to Entities using the `[EdmFunction]` attribute like explained here: [How to call DB function from EF LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002106/how-to-call-db-function-from-ef-linq-query)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities tries to translate your LINQ query into SQL. Since it doesn't know how to do `String.Split` in a SQL query, it fails.

This means that unless you want to write a SQL implementation of `String.Split`, you can only do it in LINQ to objects, which means you need to load all of your data into memory first, then do the `where` clause. One easy way to do this is using `.ToList()`:

```
var results  = (from a in Entities.TblActivities select a).ToList(); //Results are now in memory
results = results.Where(a =>
     a.Keywords.Split(',').Any(p => keyword.Contains(p))).ToList(); //This uses LINQ-to-objects
```

Comment: This may work if we're talking megabytes (at most), though it might be horribly slow. If we're talking many gigabytes, it may not even work.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I agree. Probably the right solution is either changing the database or writing custom SQL, but either of those seemed outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score -5):

**Not sure but you can try:**
    Since the error appears to be looking for an array this might work.

```
string[] keyword = keywords.Split(new char[] {','});

var results  = (from a in Entities.TblActivities
                where a.Keywords.Split(new char[] {','}).Any(p => keyword.Contains(p))
                select a).ToList();
```