# How can i handle 2 instance inside of singleorDefault by using Newton json?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

My question is not easy but not too complex to handle. i have an extention to compare 2 instance : ( i used newton json, you can prefere IEquatable etc.) 
How can i compare 2 instanve inside of singleordefault() by using Extentions. because i have lots of property and this database belongs to my customer. i don't know unique fields.

```
public static class Extention
{
    public static bool Compare(this object obj, object another)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj, another)) return true;
        if ((obj == null) || (another == null)) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != another.GetType()) return false;

        var objJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var anotherJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(another);

        return objJson == anotherJson;
    }
}
```

and i am calling this extention :

```
public static void Save(arr[] items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var entity = ctx.myTable.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Compare(item)); // ---> ERROR HERE (System.NotSupportedException)
        if (entity == null)
        {   . . . . .
```

Error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Boolean Compare(System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Compare` is a method defined by you but linq to entities queries are translated by the provider into valid sql for the targeted DBMS. The provider has no knowledge how to translate your method into sql.

You need to do one of two things:

1. define it in such a way that will be recognized by the database
   ([see nlips answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965480/6400526))
2. Use `.AsEnumerable()` before the use of the not supported method to perform filtering in memory. *Keep in mind that it means that you will bring much more data than you actually need*

Maybe a possible workaround is to pass the json to the database as a `string` and then linq to entities knows how to compare if two strings are equal

Comment: thanks for great answer. And Sorry for late response.

Comment: @programmerist - Glad it helped :)