# Linq to SQL compare two comma delimited strings

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq to SQL and I have two comma delimited strings.

`string1` is from a database table and looks like "Y,J,A,F,L,R,G".
`string2` is obtained from an object and looks like "G,L".

What I am struggling with is to check that the contents of `string2` are in `string1`.

This is what i currently have:

```
var result = from d in oTable
             where d.string1.Contains(string2)
             select d;
```

Comment: Because your string does _not_ contains `"G,L"` string. Are you looking for contains both `G` and `L` characters?

Comment: Hi Soner, yes, i am looking for contains both G and L

Comment: Why do you store multiple values comma separated instead of as single records? So instead of one value `Y,J,A,F,L,R,G` you should have 7 records in a relation table. An rdbms is not a text parser.

Comment: `var result = "G,L".All(c => "Y,J,A,F,L,R,G".Contains(c));`? But as Tim said, you should have 7 different rows for them. Maybe you don't _even_ need to this process if you save your data properly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I completely agree, though this is an inherited mess and I have been told i cannot change the structure. I'll be recommending to my client that they implement the records correctly

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for that. That works perfectly.

Comment: You might be wanting to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002106/how-to-call-db-function-from-ef-linq-query You could define a function to the database that you could use within the query, that function would then have the responsibility to do the check in sql instead of builtin memory query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
string string2 = "G,L";
var result = from item in oTable
             where string2.All(x => item.string1.Contains(x))
             select item;
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can look in `All` or `Any` methods, or use `Select` to get result for each char.

```
string first = "Y,J,A,F,L,R,G";
string second = "G,L,X";

// result for each in "second"
IEnumerable<bool> contains = second.Split(',').Select(res => first.Contains(res));
// true if all are contained in first
bool all = second.Split(',').All(res => first.Contains(res));
// true if any is contained in first
bool any = second.Split(',').Any(res => first.Contains(res));
```

Comment: `String.Split` is not supported, only if you load all into memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, data must get into memory before using something like `AsEnumerable()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Splitting the first string and the second string by a comma.
2. Then using LINQ Except ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx)) to check if all substrings of string2 are contained in string1

   ```
   string string1 = "Y,J,A,F,L,R,G";
   string string2 = "B,L";

   string[] elementsString1 = string1.Split(',');
   string[] elementsString2 = string2.Split(',');

   bool contained = !elementsString2.Except(elementsString1).Any();

   Console.WriteLine(contained);
   ```

Comment: Since this is Linq-To-Sql you first have to load the complete table into memory to get it working. I doubt that this is desired.

Comment: You are absolutely right, although the question was formed about single strings that are separated by comma. As you mentioned in your comment on the question itself - the best way is to use a relation table with separate records.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SonerGönül the below worked.

```
var result = "G,L".All(c => "Y,J,A,F,L,R,G".Contains(c));
```

Though i agree with everyone else, this is not how the data should be stored and I'll be passing that onto my client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union and Distinct.

```
var containts = string2.Union(string1).Count() == string1.Distinct().Count();
```

If Union changes the length of `string1.Distinct()` it means there was something else in string2 that was not in string1. If the length does not change (`==`) then it means every thing in string2 was also inside string1.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use, [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

See [Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V5blAo)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;      
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str="Y,J,A,F,L,R,G";
        string[] arr=str.Split(',');
        string[]  x=new String[2]{"G","r"};

        IEnumerable<String> x1=arr.Intersect(x);
        if(x1.Any())
        {
            foreach(string st in x1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Matched String: "+st);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty Matching");
        }

    }
}
```