# Entity Framework 6 code-first - map function or stored procedure to primitive types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I am looking to implement something like the following:

```
string searchValue = "Jun";
var users = context.Users
                   .Where(x => x.BirthDate.SomeWhackySqlFunction(searchTerm))
                   .ToList();
```

where `SomeWhackySqlFunction` maps to a function or stored procedure in SQL Server that takes 2 parameters:

- `value: DateTime` (in the sample code above it would be the value of birthDate).
- `searchTerm: string`

This is to get around limitations with EF , alternatively if I could extend the [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) or [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) class, this could also do the trick.

Comment: what EF limitation? also you have provided no code which shows what you have tired. Stack Overflow is not a free coding site.... you must show what you have done. Also what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Seabizkit not looking for a fully implemented solution just ideas/links to put me in the right direction. Do you know if it is possible to map a SQLServer function back to a function in C#?

Comment: yes it is possible im sure a quick google would yield results. Also please state the limitation you are facing with EF.

Comment: What is the EF limitation you are facing? Linq is fairly extensive

Comment: @Seabizkit I have done a google and only found ways to map a sqlFunction back to a whole entity not a primitive type. maybe my search terms need tweaking, if you had a link that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The limitation is in trying to do a search along the lines of: 

        var users = context.User
                 .Where(x => x.BirthDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt").Contains(searchTerm).ToList()

.. IE within EF there is no cast or convert function to convert a datetime to a string in a specific format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002106/how-to-call-db-function-from-ef-linq-query which will take you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions. EF is very powerful and has most things built in. You may find that you are making something hard by assuming its not built in and a limitation.

Comment: @Todd Take a look at this library [EntityFramework.Functions](https://github.com/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions)

Comment: @IvanStoev - Thanks for the link. And I have tried this library however have to problems: 


1 - all the functions seem to map back to an entity, I cant find an example of a function that i can call on a field.

2 - I could not get this library running within my solution

Comment: @Todd so your searchTerm is a specify date format and you are searching for this in a datetime field... it is extremely odd to search for something in this manor where using is required to input a date format, is it not simpler to convert the searchTerm to a date.

Comment: @Seabizkit - thanks for the links, looking at these example they appear to be using Model First, I am struggling to find a solution that uses Code First.

Comment: Are you using Database First (edmx)? Because that library is for Code First, and I personally can guarantee that [Scalar-valued function, composable](https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Scalar-valued_function,_composable) does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @Seabizkit, your right it is not common, hence why I am struggling with it. To give you a bit more context, from the frontend the user is searching a grid of information from a single text box for input, so the search phrase has to be across multiple columns of multiple types. so if the date in a column is displayed as "20/Jan 2017 10:04 am" and the user enters the search term J we want to return the said record.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I am using Code First, no edmx file, but your right a scaler function would do the trick.

Comment: @Todd where did "20/Jan 2017 10:04 am" come from? if u manage the code... ie have full control.. you can find the record..using the type and values behind the UI. I.e. if "20/Jan 2017 10:04 am" was populated with data from the db.. then keep this value and simply use the original representation

Comment: @Seabizkit the "20/Jan 2017 10:04 am" is stored as a datetime in the database, the formatting is set on the front end. the problem I am having is converting the datetime to the same format in an IQueryable (for example context,Users.BirthDate.ToString(""dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt").contains("jun") will throw an error because EF can not convert DateTime.ToString to SQL.

Comment: how would you covert the sql date into a string... https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-datetime-to-string-format-using-iqueryable/ maybe useful

Comment: @Seabizkit I have tried the approach mentioned  in the c-csharpconer article however struggled to get the month out in the format MMM, Ie Jun for June or Dec for December. If you know how to solve that and the am/pm part, i would be most appreciative.

Comment: @Todd yeah that is what I suspected, rather convert a hidden field which represents the something but in a better format... and then search on the actual date, rather than the exercise you are trying to achieve... well thats what i would do.